# Atualizar cabeçalhos com AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tenho um formulário AJAX que só mostra um captcha para o usuário quando o formulário for enviado mais de 2 vezes.

Eu salvo essas tentativas na `$_SESSION` com PHP, porém como o formulário é enviado via AJAX o captcha só vai aparecer quando o usuário atualizar a página mesmo ele tendo enviado o formulário mais de 2 vezes.

Isso acontece porque eu não estou atualizando os cabeçalhos acredito eu. Como eu faria isso com AJAX? Ao enviar o `form` esses dados serem atualizados?

@Edit:
No meu `contact.php` eu faço o seguinte para setar as requisições

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') $_SESSION['attemptsSendEmail'] += 1;

if ($_SESSION['attemptsSendEmail'] >= 2) {
    if(!isset($ret->captcha)){
        http_response_code(401);
        exit('Captcha errado, bloqueado pelo anti-spam');
    }
    if (isset($ret->captcha) && $ret->captcha !== $_SESSION['captcha']) {
        http_response_code(401);
        exit('Captcha errado, bloqueado pelo anti-spam');
    }
}
```

E aqui a validação no Javascript

```
waghcwb.query('#contact-form').onsubmit = function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var btn = waghcwb.query('#contact-form button[type="submit"]');


    waghcwb.post('contact/contact.php', {
            name: waghcwb.query('input[name="name"]').value,
            email: waghcwb.query('input[name="email"]').value,
            message: waghcwb.query('textarea[name="message"]').value,
            captcha: (waghcwb.query('input[name="captcha"]')) ? waghcwb.query('input[name="captcha"]').value : null

        }, function() {
            btn.style.backgroundColor = '#34DB42';
            btn.style.borderColor = '#34DB42';
            btn.setAttribute('class', 'button success');
            btn.innerHTML = '<img src="img/check.svg" alt="Enviado com sucesso" title="Enviado com sucesso">';
            waghcwb.query('input[name="captcha"]').className = '';

            if (waghcwb.query('#captchaImg')) waghcwb.query('#captchaImg').src = '/captcha/captcha.php?' + new Date().getTime();

            waghcwb.query('input[name="name"]').value = '';
            waghcwb.query('input[name="email"]').value = '';
            waghcwb.query('textarea[name="message"]').value = '';
            if (waghcwb.query('input[name="captcha"]')) waghcwb.query('input[name="captcha"]').value = '';

        }, function() {
            btn.style.backgroundColor = '#DB3434';
            btn.style.borderColor = '#DB3434';
            btn.setAttribute('class', 'button error');
            btn.innerHTML = '<img src="img/times.svg" alt="Erro ao enviar os dados" title="Erro ao enviar os dados">';
        },

        function() {
            var input_captcha = waghcwb.query('input[name="captcha"]'),
                captcha = waghcwb.query('#captchaImg');
            input_captcha.placeholder = 'O código de segurança não confere.';
            input_captcha.className = 'error';
            input_captcha.value = '';
            if (captcha) captcha.src = '/captcha/captcha.php?' + new Date().getTime();
        });
};
```

Comment: Poste o que tem feito em JS. Se você conta as tentativas use a `var` para mostrar o captcha.

Comment: Você pode incrementrar a variável sessions no PHP cada vez que o ajax o chama. Tipo `$_SESSION['visitas']+=1;` dentro do ficheiro PHP que o ajax chama

Comment: @Sergio, já faço isso no PHP, o problema é que enviando por Ajax a cada requisição isso não é atualizado na página.

Comment: @Jader, Adicionei os códigos. Se eu simplesmente recarregar o elemento form com uma nova requisição AJAX os dados da $_SESSION são atualizados?

Comment: @waghcwb se estiver tudo certo com os cookies (que passam a session ID) ou a session ID for passada corretamente pela url (o php normalmente faz isso automagicamente) deve funcionar sim...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque o seu captcha em uma div oculta, e contabilize no JS o numero de envios via ajax do formulário.  Após o envio, se o contador chegar em 2, mostre a div com jquery ou com javascript normal, passando do modo hide pra block.  Depois, no envio do formulário via js, basta conferir se o contador está acima de 2 e testar a captcha antes de enviar o form.

EDITADO:
Não sei se podia fazer uma nova resposta... mas enfim, estou editando essa aqui:

Do jeito que você fez, na verdade ficou mais fácil ainda... porque você já está passando o captcha de qualquer forma pela chamada do ajax..

Então, antes do

```
waghcwb.query('#contact-form').onsubmit = function(event) {
```

você vai criar uma variável pro seu contador:

var contadorform = 0;

e vai somar dentro do seu envio:

```
...
var btn = waghcwb.query('#contact-form button[type="submit"]');
contadorform = contadorform + 1; // ou contadorform ++;
...
```

e vai passar ela também como parâmetro pro seu contact.php

```
...
name: waghcwb.query('input[name="name"]').value,
email: waghcwb.query('input[name="email"]').value,
message: waghcwb.query('textarea[name="message"]').value,
contador: contadorform,
...
```

E pra finalizar, no contact.php, você vai testar essa variável do contador:

```
if ($_POST['contador'] >= 2) {
```

Todo o resto se dará em cima dessa variável, tanto no JS quanto no PHP.

Caso tenha restado alguma dúvida, só falar que eu comento para explicar melhor.

Comment: Quem negativou e por quê?

Comment: Talvez tenha sido pela carência de um exemplo mais ilustrativo. Da forma que respondeu ficou como um simples comentário.

Comment: Exemplo ilustrativo por exemplo ilustrativo, ele deveria ter postado o código fonte dele.  Se não postou, entende-se que ele pode entender o que é falado, visto que não precisa de ajuda para corrigir o código fonte.

Comment: **Como faço para escrever uma boa resposta?** "Ser breve é aceitável, *mas explicações mais completas são melhores.*" Eu não negativei, apenas informei um possível motivo.

Comment: @MarceloGomes, fiquei ausente alguns dias.. Mas não fui eu quem negativou sua resposta. Até porque nem havia visto ela ainda! Estou colocando o código para análise.

Comment: @waghcwb editei a resposta, mostrando com pedaços do código fonte onde as alterações devem ser feitas.  Como é ajax, o retorno não vai conseguir atualizar o session, por isso usar uma variável JS é mais funcional.  Teste pela variável JS e mostre o campo do captcha validando apenas o contador em JS...